# Why print [[Ljava.lang.Object;@12f29d9, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1648f32]

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, list, object

I have a HIBERNATE DAOImpl with this method:

```
      public List<Estados> listaEstados() throws DAOException {
    List<Estados> lista = getHibernateTemplate().find("SELECT e.id as id,e.nombre as nombre FROM Estados e");          
      return lista;
}
```

And when running, rather than painting the id and the name of the state shows me the following:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@acacc3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@825032]
```

and should paint something like this:

```
[[1,"Morelos"],[2,"Mexico"]
```

why? What am I doing wrong?

the problem is when I check 2 or more fields, if you only get the name of the state runs well.

I did a test with Junit. And before displaying lines :

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@acacc3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@825032]
```

if it is showing me results

```
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - result row: 
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.IntegerType  - returning '1' as column: col_0_0_
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - returning 'Morelos' as column: col_1_0_
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - result set row: 1
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - result row: 
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.IntegerType  - returning '2' as column: col_0_0_
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType  - returning 'Mexico' as column: col_1_0_
8585 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - done processing result set (2 rows)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, because the correct results are lost? and where you lose? or if I have to convert it to a String object or a List. As ago?, What would the code.?

Answer (score 4):

Override `toString()` method in your `Estados` to return pretty `String` that you want to see, if you are attempting to print array directly or indirectly you would want to use `Arrays.toString()` as well

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of the list as `List<Estados> lista` make it seem like it's going to be a list of `Estados`s at runtime also but it is not the case.

You actually get a list of arrays because of the way you have written your query. So you need to iterate over the list `lista` and pass each item in  the list to `Arrays.toString()` method.

Or, probably this isn't what you want, change your query to `SELECT e FROM Estados e`, in which case the `find` method will actually return a list of `Estados`s, and override the `toString` in `Estados`.